# Firestore security rules: evaluating incoming requests against other documents in the database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am new to firestore and its security rules so apologies if this sounds stupid.
I have 3 collections, data, roles and trainingRequests. In roles I am storing users id along with their name and role as shown in the image attached. What I wanted to do was to give access of read and write only if the role of the user is "external". So, for that purpose the rule I wrote is as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /trainingRequests/{tId} {
        allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles).data[request.auth.uid].role == "external"
    }
    
  }
}
```

But this is not working at all. So, I wanted to know what I am doing wrong and what's the right way to write the rule for this purpose.
I know that custom claims is a better approach but I still want to try this out.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a **document** path to the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) method.

With

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles)
```

you are actually passing the `roles` collection path.

---

The following should do the trick:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /trainingRequests/{tId} {
        allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "external"
    }
    
  }
}
```

---

The `get()` method returns a [`rules.firestore.Resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) on which you call the [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#data) property which returns a map of the document data.

You'll find more details and examples in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).